# Replace the data instead of adding data to existing one

Tags: javascript

I am having a problem with my code:

```
b1 = document.getElementById('headerVv');
var playlistId = 'id';
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", doSomething)
b1.addEventListener('click', function() {
  playlistId = 'id2';
  doSomething(playlistId)
});
```

Function `doSomething` is generating the data on my page. The general thought was to fire up the page with the default `playlistId`, but when I trigger the `eventListener` to replace the current data with new `playlistId`. Swapping the `playlistId` works, but it's adding new data to the existing data instead of replacing it. Anyone could help me fix it?

Comment: "The general thought was to fire up the page with the default playlistId, but when I trigger the eventListener to replace the current data with new playlistId" <- I can't understand

Comment: Code of `doSomething` ?

Comment: Can you post a working code so that we could help you fix the issue? Without knowing what `doSomething` is doing, we can't help here

Comment: `doSomething` generates videos from youtube API based on the `playlistId`, When I open the page I want the function to run with the default `playlistId` witch is `id`, but when I trigger `eventListener` I want to run the function with new `playlistId`, but the data from the initial run of `doSomothing` stays.

Comment: Edit your question and post the code snippet of `doSomething`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear the contents before appending the new ones:

```
function resultsLoop(data) {
  $('main').empty();
  ...
```

Also consider naming your functions/variables properly, this will be rewarded in the long term.

Comment: have you tested it on my codepen? I have added that, but still the same